# How to get non-inclusive index of substring?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a string `String s = "0123456789t:9876543210"`
How can I get the index immediately following `"t:"` (i.e, index 12)?

Is there a built-in way, or am I stuck with `s.substring(s.indexOf("t:")+2);` ?

Specifically, I'm wanting a solution for any token-length. So my token may be `t:`, or it may as easily be `test:`. Regardless of the token itself, is there a way to dynamically get the index immediately following whatever token I search on?

Comment: `s.indexOf("t:")+2` return you the index ie `12`, what else you want

Comment: This is the way you can do it.

Comment: I want something that's not a static shift. What if my token can vary from `t:` to `test:` to `testing500:`? At this point, I'm required to count the length of my token, and add that for every access. There must be a safer way.

Comment: @MrDuk - well, in that case it would be `s.indexOf(yourString + ":")+2`

Comment: make your token a variable and make a function out of it?
s.substring(s.indexOf(token)+token.length)?

Comment: You don't have to count anything. Getting the length of a String is O(1). indexOf is the slow bit.

Comment: If you're doing this purely so you can pass it into substring() -- replacing the entire expression with 
    s.split("t:")[1]
would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IndexOf like this:

```
s.indexOf(s + ":")+2
```

Comment: So, regardless of the length of `yourString`, this will always return the index immediately following `:`?

Comment: @MrDuk:- Yes thats true!

Comment: Very awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way of finding index.

[int indexOf(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

From Javadocs,

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified substring. The integer returned is the smallest value k such
>   that:
>
> ```
>  this.startsWith(str, k)
> ```

To make it dynamic, pls have a structure of this sort.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "0123456789t:9876543210";
        System.out.println(getIndex("t:", s));
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf("t:") + 2);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    private static int getIndex(String searchedText, String inputText) {
        return inputText.indexOf(searchedText) + searchedText.length();
    }
```

**output**

```
12
9876543210
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make it all modular having an arraylist of strings, with all commands and for it you can do:

```
    ArrayList<String>  al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = "123456789t:987654321";
    al.add("t:");//this is where you add your cases

    for(String c:al){
         System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf(c) + c.length));
     }
```

that way the length of the case cant be messed up b/c it is part of the string class